# iOS Swift - Offline Availability

Tags: ios, mysql, sqlite, swift

I'm building an app with iOS Swift and I'm new in this domain.

I require some contents to be available while offline, like user details, their current score, their photos etc. I wanted to know what can I use for local storage; Shall I use SQLite DB or NSUserDefaults or are there any other options available? I'll be using MySQL for remote server.

Appreciate any information.

Comment: So did you try anything or would you like us to write the app for you? I don't know what the question is. Also, read: [ask]

Comment: Huh, that was pretty encouraging for a Stackoverflow newbie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three options :

1. Storing large amount of data in `NSUserDefaults` is not a good idea.
2. Storing in SQLite is a good option.
3. Storing in CoreData is a perfect option.
4. Storing as plist file is a easy option.

Comment: Photos should not be stored in sqlite or using CoreData. Put the photos in a subfolder of the documents directory and store filenames in the database

Comment: @N J Gadhiya, Thank you for your prompt response. Just out of curiosity (what veterans have been doing!) if you were building an Instagram clone, what option would you use for offline availability of user information, uploaded contents etc?

Comment: For CoreData or SQLite you will have to make same data structure as instagram. I would suggest to use plist, because plist stores the whole dictionary or array as it is. But remind that plists are slower than SQLite or CoreData, so you have to divide one dictionary into multiple and store them all as saperate plist.

Comment: @NJGadhiya, Thanks for your response. Appreciate!

Comment: Welcome and feel free to ask if you have any further queries, Best of luck.